# pick random records from csv and add t.hem in SharePoint List

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a CSV file which contains Names and Email ID's of all employees and here I need to run a powershell script to pick(1000 records at regular intervals) random Names/Email ID's from CSV file and add them in the SharePoint list.

I also need to ensure that picked user are removed from CSV file so that they are not added again in the SP List

Here is the script which is working fine to pick a specific count of records:

```
Import-Csv D:\Sachchin.csv | Get-Random -Count 300 | Select-Object Name
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Sachchin. SO works well when people post the code they are trying to make work, tell what it is doing, and tell what they want it to do. Give us your code that doesn't work. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ImportList  = Import-Csv D:\Sachchin.csv
$RandomList  = $ImportList | Get-Random -Count 300
$RandomNames = $RandomList | Select-Object Name

# Export =>
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ImportList -DifferenceObject $RandomList | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject | 
        Export-Csv D:\Sachchin.csv -NoTypeInformation
```